# deleting lightbox from category grid view gallery

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone know how to delete the lightbox from the Category Grid View Gallery plugin on Wordpress?

I can't figure it out for the life of me, and their website no longer works.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to ask this on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com :)

Comment: Thanks! I'll go over there now.